# Laravel composer install failed

Tags: php, laravel

I pulled my laravel installation from my remote server to my local machine and want now to execute 'composer install' to install all required packages. The whole thing worked in the past smoothly. But now I receive this error:

> - laravel/framework v5.1.17 requires symfony/dom-crawler 2.7.* -> satisfiable by symfony/dom-crawler[2.7.x-dev, v2.7.0, v2.7.0-BETA1,
>     v2.7.0-BETA2, v2.7.1, v2.7.10, v2.7.11, v2.7.12, v2.7.13, v2.7.14,
>     v2.7.15, v2.7.16, v2.7.17, v2.7.18, v2.7.19, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.7.4,
>     v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.7.8, v2.7.9] but these conflict with your
>     requirements or minimum-stability.

My composer.json looks like this:

```
> {
>     "name": "laravel/laravel",
>     "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
>     "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
>     "license": "MIT",
>     "type": "project",
>     "require": {
>         "php": ">=5.5.9",
>         "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
>         "league/fractal": "^0.12.0",
>         "pda/pheanstalk": "^3.1",
>         "witty/laravel-push-notification": "dev-master",
>         "illuminate/html": "^5.0",
>         "way/generators": "^3.0",
>         "laracasts/generators": "^1.1"
>     },
>     "require-dev": {
>         "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
>         "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
>         "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
>         "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1",
>         "symfony/dom-crawler": "~3.0"
>     },
>     "autoload": {
>         "classmap": [
>             "database"
>         ],
>         "psr-4": {
>             "App\\": "app/"
>         }
>     },
>     "autoload-dev": {
>         "classmap": [
>             "tests/TestCase.php"
>         ]
>     },
>     "scripts": {
>         "post-install-cmd": [
>             "php artisan clear-compiled",
>             "php artisan optimize"
>         ],
>         "pre-update-cmd": [
>             "php artisan clear-compiled"
>         ],
>         "post-update-cmd": [
>             "php artisan optimize"
>         ],
>         "post-root-package-install": [
>             "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
>         ],
>         "post-create-project-cmd": [
>             "php artisan key:generate"
>         ]
>     },
>     "config": {
>         "preferred-install": "dist"
>     } }
```

I haven't changed a single bit of my code but just did a clean install of my computer.

When I try to change to dom-crawler ~2.7 I get this error:

```
>  Problem 1
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.45
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.44
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.43
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.42
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework 5.2.41
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.40
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.39
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.38
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.37
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.36
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.35
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.34
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.33
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.32
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.31
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.30
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.29
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.28
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.27
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.26
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.25
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.24
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.23
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.22
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.21
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.20
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.19
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.18
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.17
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.16
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.15
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.14
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.13
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.12
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.11
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.10
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.9
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.8
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.7
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.6
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.5
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.4
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.3
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.2
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.1
>     - witty/laravel-push-notification dev-master requires illuminate/support 5.0.* | 5.1.* -> satisfiable by
> laravel/framework[v5.1.17], illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v5.0.22,
> v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.28, v5.0.33, v5.0.4, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16,
> v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41,
> v5.1.6, v5.1.8].
>     - witty/laravel-push-notification dev-master requires illuminate/support 5.0.* | 5.1.* -> satisfiable by
> laravel/framework[v5.1.17], illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v5.0.22,
> v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.28, v5.0.33, v5.0.4, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16,
> v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41,
> v5.1.6, v5.1.8].
>     - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v5.2.0, v5.1.17].
>     - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0
>     - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.22|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0
>     - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.25|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0
>     - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.26|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0
>     - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0
>     - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.33|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0
>     - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0
>     - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0
>     - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.13|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0
>     - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0
>     - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0
>     - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.20|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0
>     - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.22|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0
>     - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.25|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0
>     - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0
>     - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.30|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0
>     - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.31|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0
>     - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.41|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0
>     - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0
>     - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0
>     - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.2.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.2.41, v5.2.0, v5.2.1, v5.2.10, v5.2.11,
> v5.2.12, v5.2.13, v5.2.14, v5.2.15, v5.2.16, v5.2.17, v5.2.18,
> v5.2.19, v5.2.2, v5.2.20, v5.2.21, v5.2.22, v5.2.23, v5.2.24, v5.2.25,
> v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.29, v5.2.3, v5.2.30, v5.2.31, v5.2.32,
> v5.2.33, v5.2.34, v5.2.35, v5.2.36, v5.2.37, v5.2.38, v5.2.39, v5.2.4,
> v5.2.40, v5.2.42, v5.2.43, v5.2.44, v5.2.45, v5.2.5, v5.2.6, v5.2.7,
> v5.2.8, v5.2.9].
>     - Installation request for witty/laravel-push-notification dev-master -> satisfiable by
> witty/laravel-push-notification[dev-master].
```

Comment: Laravel requires Symfony DomCrawler component in version 2.7 but you installing it in version 3.0 in dev version. Probably on remote server you do not have installed dev libraries.

Comment: Have you run composer update?
What happens when you try to change "symfony/dom-crawler": "~3.0" to "symfony/dom-crawler": "~2.7"?

Comment: Just tried ~2.7. Then the error appears mentioned above in the update of the post

Comment: From Laravel 5.2 `composer.json`: `"symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*"`. With installed Laravel you have an installed DomCrawler so you should just remove dom crawler from your composer.json.

Comment: Do you have `composer.lock` file? Now I see composer is trying to install Laravel 5.1 when you specified Laravel 5.2 in json file.

Comment: I deleted the lock file

Comment: But I wonder why he is searching for 5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Library `witty/laravel-push-notification` is too old to install Laravel in version 5.2. One of dependencies of `laravel-push-notification` is `illuminate/support` in version `"5.0.* | 5.1.*"`.

You're trying to install Laravel 5.2 but that library needs Laravel 5.1 to works.

P.S. Also try to not remove `composer.lock` next time, sometimes it can save project.